# Display a countdown timer for web query refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, power-query

I have a web query set up to refresh data when the workbook is opened and then refresh data every 15 minutes, but I would like to display the last refresh time and the remaining time left until the next refresh as a visual countdown.

There is also a manual refresh button if you don't want to wait the 15 minutes so I would need something to insert into the refresh VBA script to reset the timer to 15 minutes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to resort to VBA for a Visual countdown. But to get the last refresh time, you can add a blank query in your query editor and add the below code in the formula bar

```
= Time.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
```

Then when you load this data to excel, you can use the Now and Time formula's to get the time remaining. But it will not keep updating every second/minute.